# Uploadify plugin doesn't pass more than 1 param

Tags: jquery, post, parameters, uploadify

There is issue, when Uploadify plugin desn't POST more than **1** parameter.
Tried 3 variants below.
Any suggestions or experince?

**First - standard way**
***explanation***: *portletId* and *jsessionid* params passed in 'script' :

```
oScript.text = "var $j = jQuery.noConflict();";
oScript.text+= "$j(document).ready(function(){";
...
oScript.text+= "$j('#uploadify').uploadify({";
oScript.text+= "'script'   : '<%= request.getContextPath()%>/uploadFile?portletId=${portletId}&jsessionid=${pageContext.session.id}',"; 
...
```

**Second - with 'scriptData'**
***explanation***: *portletId* remained, *jsessionid* moved to 'scriptData':

```
oScript.text = "var $j = jQuery.noConflict();";
oScript.text+= "$j(document).ready(function(){";
...
oScript.text+= "$j('#uploadify').uploadify({";
oScript.text+= "'script'   : '<%= request.getContextPath()%>/uploadFile?portletId=${portletId}',"; 
oScript.text+= "'scriptData' : {'jsessionid':'${pageContext.session.id}'},";
...
```

**Third - with events *onSelect* and *onOpen***
 (tried both,descriped in [Problem sending additional post data to server with uploadify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970558/problem-sending-additional-post-data-to-server-with-uploadify))
***explanation***: *portletId* remained and *jsessionid* is set on event (*onSelect* or *onOpen*):

```
oScript.text = "var $j = jQuery.noConflict();";
oScript.text+= "$j(document).ready(function(){";
...
oScript.text+= "$j('#uploadify').uploadify({";
oScript.text+= "'script'   : '<%= request.getContextPath()%>/uploadFile?portletId=${portletId}',"; 

oScript.text+= "'onOpen' : function(){";
oScript.text+= "$j('#uploadify').uploadifySettings(";
oScript.text+= "'scriptData', {'jsessionid':'${pageContext.session.id}'});}";
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved.
You should use 'GET' value as 'method' param mandatory.
And 'scriptData' correspondingly.

see details here:
[uploadify forum post](http://www.uploadify.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=4847)