# Request for help with uploadify

Tags: jquery

I need some help with [jQuery uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). When uploading, I want to add two fields (name and description) in the form, and I want to receive this data on the upload.php file. I think this can be done by using **scriptData** but I dont understand how I can send the values of these two fields and receive on the upload.php file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fileUpload").fileUpload({
        'uploader': 'uploadify/uploader.swf',
        'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
        'script': 'uploadify/upload.php',
        'folder': 'files',
        'multi': false,
        'displayData': 'speed'
    });


});

</script>
```

And here is upload form with the fields:

```
<fieldset>
        <h2>File Upload</h2>
        Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br />
        Description: <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="desc" >Enter Description</textarea>:<br /> 
        <div id="fileUpload">You have a problem with your javascript</div>
        <a href="javascript:$('#fileUpload').fileUploadStart()">Start Upload</a> |  <a href="javascript:$('#fileUpload').fileUploadClearQueue()">Clear Queue</a>
        <p></p>
    </fieldset>
```

I will be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define a function called upload:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fileUpload").fileUpload({
        'uploader': 'uploadify/uploader.swf',
        'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
        'script': 'uploadify/upload.php',
        'folder': 'files',
        'multi': false,
        'displayData': 'speed'
    });


});

    function upload(){
        var ipName = $("input[name='name']").val();
        var ipDesc = $("textarea[name='desc']").val();
        var data = {name:ipName, desc:ipDesc};
        $('#fileUpload').uploadifySettings("scriptData", data).fileUploadStart();
    }



</script>
```

Then change your upload anchor to as follows:

```
<fieldset>
        <h2>File Upload</h2>
        Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br />
        Description: <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="desc" >Enter Description</textarea>:<br /> 
        <div id="fileUpload">You have a problem with your javascript</div>
            <a href="javascript:upload()">Start Upload</a> |
            <a href="javascript:$('#fileUpload').fileUploadClearQueue()">Clear Queue</a>
        <p></p>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I tried to add this js function inside the javascript script tag, before the jquery code and changed the upload link as well, but it does not do anything. Can you please tell me how to use it? Also, tell me please how I can receive the data on the php file? thanks again.

Comment: no, i dont get any error. when i click on the link, just nothing happens. could you please combine the code? may be im doing some mistake.. Thanks.

Comment: I have combined the code. Chck and let me know if you find anything different

Comment: It doesnt do anything by clicking the link. What I have understood is clicking the function does not pass the field values to the upload function. Do you know how I can pass the parameters to the upload function? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer to this somewhat related questions:

[Problem sending additional post data to server with uploadify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970558/problem-sending-additional-post-data-to-server-with-uploadify)

Answer (score 0):

I use this function and it works fine. Somebody here in StackOverflow helped me with this some time ago.

```
$(function () {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'swf': 'js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader': 'Uploadify.ashx',
            'cancelImg': 'js/uploadify/uploadify-cancel.png',
            'multi': true,
            'auto': true,
            'onQueueComplete': function (uploads) {
                $author.val('');
                $title.val('');                    
            },
            'onUploadStart': function (file) {
                $("#file_upload").uploadify("settings", 'formData', { 'attFolder': 'Attach', 'idProject': $idProject, 'idClient': $idClient, 'auth': $author.val(), 'tit': $title.val() });
            }
        });
```

Title                                            
                                                 
                    

                                                                
                                              
                        Author                                            
                                                              
                    

                                                                
                                              
                        Select Attachment(s) to Upload