# Uploadify updateSettings problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I've got an uploadify form working beautifully, but I'd like to change the settings programatically and I'm getting an error.

Uploadify is initiated on document.ready and I'm trying to bind the updateSettings to a button click (also done in the document.ready). I have also tried using the updateSettings function outside of the document.ready - actually on the button or just inline script to get the same error.

The error is

```
Error: document.getElementById(a(this).attr("id") + "Uploader").updateSettings is not a function
```

And my code currently looks like

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#uploadify').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : 'uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : 'uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : 'cancel.png',
    'auto'      : true,
    'folder'    : '/uploads'
  });

  $("#changeIt").click(function(){
    $("#uploadify").uploadifySettings("folder","something_else");
  });

});
</script>

<input type="file" name="uploadify" id="uploadify" />

<a id="changeIt" src="#">Change the upload dir</a>
```

Like I say, I've tried adding the uploadifySettings outside the document.ready, I've also tried adding it right in an onclick in the a tag itself to get the same error. I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes? It shouldn't matter, but one never knows...

Comment: I have yes, no change I'm afraid.

Comment: I experienced exactly the same problem. But I don't remember what I did. What if you move your script to a JS file? That's what I have done. And I'm also using uploadifySettings.

Comment: It is possible to bind Uploadify to file inputs, I do the same currently. Any chance the input is in a panel initially hidden or display set to "none"?

Answer (score 2):

You code is wrong. Uploadify cannot binded to a `<input type="file">`, only to a `<div/>`. See the documentation and the example in the uploadify site.

To have progressive enhancement, I have both element, `<input type="file"/>` and an empty `<div/>`. Then in javascript code, I remove the input element and then initialize uploadify.

```
<input type="file" name="uploadify" />
<div id="uploadify"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
      $("input[name='uploadify']").hide().remove();
      $("#uploadify").uploadify({UPLOADIFY_PARAM});
      //a click handler to change uploadify param
      //...
    });
    </script>
```

Btw, I never consider the folder parameter from uploadify. I define the upload folder in the server side scripting.

Comment: I know that I am a little late to commenting on your post; however, Uploadify can be binded to an input of type file. As far as I know, this capability was available at the time of this question as well. Check out [implementing-uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/implementing-uploadify/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different function name. I had a similar problem and found out that renaming `updateSettings()` to `updateForm()` solved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem.
It seems that there's a bug with `auto:true`, as I have another `uploadify` on the same page, with `auto:false`, and `uploadifySettings` works perfectly.

I've made a workaround:

- set auto to false
- `onSelect`, submit the upload, like this:

  `...
  'onSelect'  : function(event, data){
                              $('#someID').uploadifySettings('param', 'value');
                              $('#someID').uploadifyUpload();
                          }
  ...`

hth

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using Uploadify inside a jquery dialog box.

The solution was to initialize Uploadify after the dialog was created.

Comment: Would you elaborate on this? I have the same problem, only in Chrome. If I remove the jquery dialog, it works. I've tried initializing the uploader on the dialag created event with no luck.

Comment: It's possible the dialog still isn't created on that event. try added a setTimeout delay (for testing). If it works with a setTimeout, then you need to find another event to attach to.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error in Chrome when the uploadify control was inside a jquery dialog.

I ended up not using uploadify and switched to jQuery Upload File Plugin http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php