# .uploadifySettings not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, uploadify

I'm using [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/) and the function to change the settings doesn't seem to be working.

I'm basing my code from the following example:

```
#(‘#someID’).uploadifySettings(’scriptData’, {‘name’ : some.val()});
```

So here's what I'm doing:

```
// INITIALIZATION
$("#"+elementId).uploadify({ 
  // other data
  "scriptData": {
     "token": token
  }
});
```

Later on I want to update the scriptData:

```
$("#"+elementId).uploadifySettings("scriptData",{"token": "pleasework"});
```

... but this is not working, it's still using the scriptData set during the initialization.

What am I doing wrong?

---

UPDATE: I need to do this because I need to handle tokens. Here's the worflow:

```
1- Get a token
2- Init uploadify with this token
3- Upload a file
4- Get another token asynchronously
5- Add the token to the already initialized uploadify (bugged)
6- Go to 3
```

I tried doing this on initialization:

```
"scriptData": {
   "token": $(".token").val()
}
```

... and update .token on step 4

This doesn't work either

UPDATE 2: Also if I do:

```
"scriptData": {
   "token": getAToken()
}
```

with

```
function getAToken(){
  alert("abcd");
  return "sometoken";
}
```

... I can see that the function getAToken only gets called once (only 1 alert)

Comment: Do you have a demo page to show us? It might be a problem with another part of your script.

Comment: @neb: No I'm sorry. It's on the admin section of an unannounced project :\

Comment: @neb: but aside from this issue, the rest of the script works perfectly

Comment: @marcgg
Im not sure on this then but best thing to do is get firebug for firefox(or google chrome inspector) to track your results step by step. Start off with a simple "uploadifySettings" change and keep goin until you find the problem.

Comment: @neb I tried this and didn't find anything, that's why I ended up posting this question ^^

Comment: i think you must invert the process use first `uploadifySettings()` for default functionality then overwrite it with `uploadify()` for specific purpose

Comment: @aseptik: what do you mean? I'm using uploadifySettings() to change some value onces I already run uploadify()

Comment: i think uploadifySettings() cant be used for override params after, but is used to set it before! just like $.ajaxSetup does with jquery AJAX! but is just my thought! ;)

Comment: @aseptik: oh. then isn't there a way to change the settings once they are set?

Comment: sure, i have alreay response to you about this! have you tried to invert the function order!?

Comment: @aseptik: if I call again uploadify() wouldn't that reload the flash and everything?

Comment: To avoid red herrings: do you also use curly singlequotes in real code?

Comment: @balusC: I use " in the code, based on uploadify's documentation

Comment: @neb, @aseptik, @balusC: in case that could help you help me, I added more info about what I've been trying and the reason of all that

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, adding a unique nonce to every file upload

```
            function setScriptData(){
                $("#product_attachment").uploadifySettings("scriptData", 
                    {
                      '_fsg_distro_session' : '<%= u cookies["_fsg_distro_session"] %>',
                      'authenticity_token'  : '<%= u form_authenticity_token if protect_against_forgery? %>',
                      'nonce'                               : new Date().getTime() + "<%= @current_user.id %>"                    
                    }
                );
                console.debug($("#product_attachment").uploadifySettings("scriptData"));
            }

            $("#product_attachment").uploadify({
                uploader                    : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                script              : '/products/temp_upload',
                cancelImg           : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
                fileDataName        : 'asset[temp_file]',
                'queueID'           : 'fileQueue',
                onComplete              : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data){ fileOnCompleteHandler(event,data); },
                onSelect                    : setScriptData,
                auto                : true,
                multi               : false,
                buttonImg           : '/images/attach.png',
                fileNameMaxLength   : 30
            });
```

I am using the latest Uploadify (2.1.0) and JQuery (1.4.1)

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I'm using jquery 1.4.2 but I doubt it's the problem. I'll take a look at your solution when I get a moment this week

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at the source and I notice that `uploadifySettings()` has an optional, undocumented (it does not appear [here](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/)) third parameter. Apparently if you set it to `true` as in `$("#"+elementId).uploadifySettings("scriptData",{"token": "pleasework"}, true);` it will clobber the existing settings for `scriptData` and perhaps that will have some impact.

But based on the source I can't exactly tell what impact a change in settings necessarily has.

```
    uploadifySettings:function(settingName, settingValue, resetObject) {
        var returnValue = false;
        jQuery(this).each(function() {
            if (settingName == 'scriptData' && settingValue != null) {
                if (resetObject) {
                    var scriptData = settingValue;
                } else {
                    var scriptData = jQuery.extend(settings.scriptData, settingValue);
                }
                var scriptDataString = '';
                for (var name in scriptData) {
                    scriptDataString += '&' + name + '=' + escape(scriptData[name]);
                }
                settingValue = scriptDataString.substr(1);
            }
            returnValue = document.getElementById(jQuery(this).attr('id') + 'Uploader').updateSettings(settingName, settingValue);
        });
```

That code is from version `2.1.0`.

Is there a way to potentially decide on the settings before initialization?

Also, I found this existing SO question: [Uploadify updateSettings problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037605/uploadify-updatesettings-problems).

Comment: nice find, I'll look more into this today and give an update here

Comment: @artlung: I tried setting the resetObject to trye and it didn't change anything. And now there is now way of deciding the settings before since they will have to change.

Comment: What setting exactly are you changing? What values change?

Comment: @artlung: In order to upload something I need to pass along a token. After the first upload, the token expires. There is a callback to get a new token once the image is uploaded, and I need to set the uploadify to pass this new token as a parameter (does it makes sense?)

Comment: What if you set the setting to a function that refers to a function that returns a current token? so wherever the token is set instead of `{ 'myToken': 'B12345' }` you do `{ 'myToken' : currentMyToken() }` then all you need to do is to reset `currentMyToken()`'s value. Have it return the current token: `var currentMyToken = function() { return 'B12345'; };` 

{}

Comment: Then update it when you need to: `currentMyToken = function() { return 'X999999'; };`

Comment: @artlung: this might work, but since I can have multiple uploaders on the same page and want to keep a generic way of creating them this might cause problems. I'll try something like that right now, but I'd still prefer to have uploadifysettings() working ^^

Comment: @artlung: I tried and it failed :\ I updated my question to add more info about what I tried

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the function in-line at initialization? IE:

```
"scriptData": {
   "token": function() { return $("#token").val(); }
}
```

I'm not sure why this would be different than some of your other solutions though.

Comment: If I try to do that, it tries to pass the function as a parameter, it doesn't actually execute it. Server side I end up with a  pretty funky DB call: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_id FROM `tokens` WHERE (`tokens`.`value` = 'function () {\n return el.find(\".token\").val();\n}')

Comment: doh!  Maybe uploadify can't handle that.  Sorry man, your original solution looks like it's straight out of Uploadify's docs.  I suppose it goes without saying that you've got the latest version and that the call to uploadifysettings is being executed correctly...  Sometimes I hate javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

**FOUND THE SOLUTION:**

I had a mistake in the "onSelect" function. I had misspelled the element id name, instead file_upload I had fileUpload and thats why it didnt update the scriptData parameter. I know its a silly mistake but easy to be made. Here is the whole onSelect function:

```
'onSelect' : function(event,data) {
            $("#file_upload").uploadifySettings('scriptData', {'id' : $('#name_of_the_element').val()}
            );
        }
```

So check if this is the problem