# Internet Explorer "Security error" uploadify

Tags: jquery, flash, security, uploadify

i am using uploadify 2.1.4, http://www.uploadify.com

local js:

```
jQuery('#file_upload').uploadify({
   'buttonImg' : 'public/uploadify/newfile.png',
   'uploader' : 'http://remoteserver/uploadify.swf',
   'scriptAccess' : 'always', ...
```

in remote server I have this crossdomain:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I edit uploadify.fla and put this code:

```
import flash.system.Security;
...
Security.allowDomain("*");
```

and so generate a new uploadify.swf

The problem is:
work with Firefox, Safari, Chrome e Opera, but in IE ( v7, v8 , v9 ( i dont test with v6 ) ) still receive error: Security Error ( in .uploadifyQueueItem )

Comment: I think you are really confused on what you are trying to achieve. Why don't you start with posting the full error code so we can determine exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure why you would use jquery to upload to a server when you can do it straight from flash (since you are already using flash anyways). This is how i do it and i have no problems in IE. Sorry i can't answer your question directly i don't know enough JQuery.

```
 var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest( "http://remoteserver/uploadify.swf" );
 request.data = myjpeg;
 request.contentType = "image/jpeg";
 request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
 var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(  );
 loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, handleResponse );
 loader.load( request );
 function handleResponse (evt:Event) { 
 trace(evt.target.data); //print response from server if there is one
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem:

in my js:

```
jQuery('#file_upload').uploadify({
  script: '/upload',
  uploader: 'http://domain.com/uploadify.swf'
```

But, when a printed (requestURL.url) in uploadify.swf, puts: "http://www.domain.com/upload"; so then flash causes security error because "http://www.dom..." != "http://dom..."

Answer (score 0):

I didn follow how you fixed the IE security issue while uploading files from one server to another.

My uploadify.swf is hosted on server 1 and upload php script is on server 2.
Crossdomain.xml on server 2 is having directives to allow upload.

Works fine in FF, Chrome, Safari but IE throws security blocker.

Thanks
Melwyn

Answer (score 0):

Hi i got solution from another question.
[dynamically setting properties in uploadify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898825/dynamically-setting-properties-in-uploadify)

Add the below property to avoid security exception in IE8

```
  'method' : 'GET',
```

It is working for me now. My total code looks like as below

```
$('#file_uploads').uploadify({
        'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {
            $scope.uploadedFileList.push(JSON.parse(data)[0].files);
            $scope.$apply();
        },
        'onQueueComplete': function (queueData) {

        },
        'onDialogClose': function (queueData) {
            //            console.log(queueData);
            if (queueData.filesSelected > 5 || (queueData.filesSelected + $scope.uploadedFileList.length) > 5) {
                bootbox.alert({
                    title: CommonUtility.errorLabel,
                    message: "Maximum 5 files allowed.",
                    callback: function () {

                    }
                });
                $('#file_uploads').data('uploadify').queueData = "";
            } else if (queueData.queueSize > 5000000) {
                bootbox.alert({
                    title: CommonUtility.errorLabel,
                    message: "Total file size should not exceed 5 MB",
                    callback: function () {

                    }
                });
            } else
                $('#file_uploads').uploadify('upload', '*');
        },
        'auto': false,
        'fileTypeExts': '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png; *.doc; *.pdf; *.xls; *.zip;',
        'scriptAccess': 'always',
        'swf': 'assets/css/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader': 'uploadfile',
        'method': 'GET',
        'buttonText': 'Browse',
    });
```